# How to insert a snippet inside XML documentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Why can't I insert a snippet inside an XML documentation field in C#?  When the cursor is inside a field, e.g. between `<param name="sender">` and `</param>` and you right-click, the `Insert Snippet` command is grayed out:

[image]

It works in VB:

[image]

Comment: Worked for me.  From project menu added new item : XML File.  Then right clicked to add Snippet.  What version of VS are you using?

Comment: you can place your cursor on that place and type, like I do.

Comment: @jdweng -- Can you see the pictures?  I'm not creating an XML file.  I'm using a regular code file with XML documentation attached to a method.  VS version is tagged.

Comment: @Hein -- I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @roryap: well it's easy. like you are writing XML between `>` and `<`.

Comment: @Hein -- I still don't understand.  What does that have to do with the "Insert Snippet" context menu item being grayed out?